# No tests are executed while using junit Categories

Tags: maven, spring-boot, junit, junit4

I am trying to run tests based on categories but doesn't seem to work. I have spring boot application

`Pom.xml` is

```
...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                            <version>2.17</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

And I have defined categories as well

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot.controller;

public interface FastTests {

}
```

and junit is just to test

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot.controller;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;

public class B {

    @Category({ FastTests.class })
    @Test
    public void c() {

        System.out.println("Hello \n\n\n\n\n");
    }
}
```

but when I try to run maven command

```
mvn test -Dgroups="com.in28minutes.springboot.controller.FastTests"
```

no tests are executed. I assume it should execute test from class `B`.